# Microsoft Exchange invitations in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, exchange-2007

I've found many suggestions on the internet, but no solutions that have worked yet. I have Thunderbird 17.0.7, ExQuilla 21.0 (for Exchange access), connecting to Mailbox server Microsoft Exchange version 8.3.83.0 (apparently a [variant](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/determine-the-version-of-microsoft-exchange-server-my-account-connects-to-HA010117038.aspx) of Microsoft Exchange Server 2007). When receiving Exchange invitations in Thunderbird, I cannot view the invitation. I only see the message Subject, and not the date, time, place, ability to RSVP, etc. The message body appears completely blank. I have 'Display Attachments Inline' enabled. When opening the invitation in Microsoft Outlook, it appears as expected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Lightning add-on.  Once Thunderbird has a calendar it will know what to do with the calendar files your on about.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I also have Lightning installed, I simply didn't mention it since I thought it wouldn't (shouldn't) be necessary. In any event, despite having Lightning and ExQuilla installed, my Exchange invitations in my Inbox still appear blank. Any other ideas?